# Read and Display PDF file from Isolated Storage in a windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-phone-8, pdf-viewer

I want to read a Pdf file from the Isolated Storage and Display it in a pdf viewer. But to my knowledge Windows phone 8 doesnt not have a pdf control. Is there any third party control I can use? or Is there any other way to display the pdf file in Windows phone 8 app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three routes:

1. Launch the pdf, which would cause it to be opened in another application
2. Pay for an already implemented control, such as [this one](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioWindowsPhone/). Note how they bundle a bunch of stuff together, so you won't just get a pdf viewer
3. Make your own pdf viewer, which is definitely the hardest way.

Edit:
How to launch an app associated with a file:

```
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(<filename>);
Launcher.LauncheFileAsync(file);
```

You can call this from wherever you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I would like to know how to launch the pdf file from isolated storage in adobe reader or any other applications like that.

Comment: @Shivangi I editted my response to include instructions on that.

Comment: thanks again. Will this work if the <filename> is an isolated storage path?

Comment: @steveg89 this code is useful but I am getting error in this code in opening excel documents. I am getting error like this, "Excel doesn't recognize file format"..Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
// get the assets folder for the app
StorageFolder folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Folder");

// get the file included in app "Folder"
StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("test.pdf");
```